# How to invoke a method when a combobox is selected passing the id?

Tags: jhipster

Let's say I have an Address ---> Country relationship. The Address form has a combobox of countries. When I select a country I invoke a method with the selected country.

```
<select #countryCB class="form-control" id="field_country" name="country" [(ngModel)]="sponsorAgreement.country" required (change)="onChangeCountry(countryCB.value)">
  <option [ngValue]="countryOption.id === address.country?.id ? address.country : countryOption"
```

The problem with this code, is that it passes the index (the 1st country in the list, the 2nd...) not the ID of the country.

I tried to debug the code and noticed that the ID is not on the combo itself, and that there is a `trackByCountryID` mechanism that I don't get. This is what is generated, as you can see, no ID:

```
<select class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="field_country" name="country" ng-reflect-name="country" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]"> 

<option value="0: null"></option> 
<option value="1: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">Andorra</option>
<option value="2: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="3: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">Afghanistan</option>
```

So with this:

```
<option [ngValue]="countryOption.id === address.country?.id ? address.country : countryOption"
```

It generates the following HTML code (with the index):

```
<option value="2: Object"
```

But if we change it to this:

```
<option [ngValue]="countryOption.id === address.country?.id ? address.country.id : countryOption.id"
```

It generates the following HTML (with the id)

```
<option value="1001: 1001"
```

But then the REST service breaks on the back when creating/updating

```
Bad Request: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Country: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (4); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Country: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (4)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5b2dbc6b; line: 8, column: 14] (through reference chain: io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Address["country"])
2017-11-18 07:55:44.081  WARN 43780 --- [ XNIO-2 task-14] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Country: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (4); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Country: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (4)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5b2dbc6b; line: 8, column: 14] (through reference chain: io.quantixx.sponsor.domain.Address["country"])
```

Does anybody know how to get the id ? Is the `trackByCountryID` involved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out what the trackBy does, but I don't need it in my use case.

So I found out what to do to pass the selected object to a method, when you choose an element in the combobox. You need to use the `ngModelChange` and then pass the `$event`. The selected element will automatically be passed to the method:

```
        <select class="form-control" id="field_sponsor" name="sponsor" [(ngModel)]="sponsorAgreement.sponsor" required (ngModelChange)="onChangeSponsor($event)">
            <option *ngIf="!editForm.value.sponsor" [ngValue]="null" selected></option>
            <option [ngValue]="sponsorOption.id === sponsorAgreement.sponsor?.id ? sponsorAgreement.sponsor : sponsorOption" *ngFor="let sponsorOption of sponsors; trackBy: trackSponsorById">{{sponsorOption.organisation.name}} - {{sponsorOption.sponsorLevel.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

Here is the `onChangeSponsor` method:

```
onChangeSponsor(sponsor: Sponsor): void {
   // the sponsor parameter is set
}
```